# Android perform button click event on navigation drawer item selected

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am using an Android material navigation drawer for my app and am trying to create a log out button as one of the navigation drawer items

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
```

//        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment;
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 9:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null)

    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    }
```

on case 9 I want to allow the user to log out,

```
Intent logOut = new Intent(GroupHomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
        logOut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

How can I allow the codes above to be executed on case 9?

Comment: Why don't you just put the code.. under case 9? Or am I not getting the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is what I think you should do :

```
  Fragment fragment = null;

switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment;
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        break;
    case 9:
        fragment=null;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if (fragment != null)

{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

} 
  else {

Intent logOut = new Intent(GroupHomeActivity.this, ElgarLoginActivity.class);
    getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
    logOut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

   }
```

**Simply because the return type is expecting a non null fragment. Well just return a null fragment, and on null logout the user.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would handle the logic for the position 9 click

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        if(position == 9){
            Intent logOut = new Intent(GroupHomeActivity.this, ElgarLoginActivity.class);
            getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
            logOut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        }else{
            switchFragment(position);
        }

}
```

Here is how you would switch the fragments.

```
private void switchFragment(int position){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment;
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your code after case 9 before break. Like this:

```
Case 9:
Intent logOut = new Intent(GroupHomeActivity.this, ElgarLoginActivity.class);
getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();     logOut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
StartActivity(logout);
break;
```